# In Minecraft Bedrock, will Nether Wart respawn in fortresses?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Basically, I picked all the nether wart from a nether fortress I could find, only to die on the way back home. Does anyone know if the nether wart will regrow near the staircase or if there’s another method to get the nether warts?

Answer (score 4):

No. Unless you replanted them, nether wart will not regrow in fortresses. However, all is not lost, because there may be more than one place in the fortress that has them. But if there aren't, you'll have to find another fortress. Too bad, I'm afraid!

Next time, consider replanting the nether wart. When broken, fully grown nether wart will always drop more than one nether wart, so you can replant them in the same spots and keep the excess. For example, if you break 10 fully-grown nether warts, you will get 2-4 nether warts per broken plant, and with the Fortune enchantment, you could get even more! That way, you will have anywhere between 20 and 40 nether warts after breaking only 10. You replant 10 of them, and you'll have between 10 and 30 to spare.

If you keep this up, you could potentially have an infinite source of nether wart!

Note that if you break the nether wart *before* it's fully grown, it will only drop one nether wart. And if you die with it in your inventory, it's gone forever.

So the key points are: Don't break nether wart until it's fully grown, and always replant the nether wart you broke.

Learn more about these mechanics on the Minecraft Wiki:

- [Nether Wart](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether_Wart)
- [Nether Fortress](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether_Fortress)
- [Fortune Enchantment](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fortune)